# Excel VBA to copy data from multiple workbook based on cell fill color

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code and it works fine with the range in source file. I have almost 1100 files in folder where cell ranges are different, but one thing is common, the heading are highlighted Yellow.

I will be very thankful if someone help me change the code, where vba copy the range after the yellow highlighted (fill) color.

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim NRow As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim DestRange As Range

' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = "C:\C Files\Yield \2016\01.30.16\"

' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
NRow = 1

' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
Do While FileName <> ""
    ' Open a workbook in the folder
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

    ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
    SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

    ' Set the source range to be A9 through C9.
    ' Modify this range for your workbooks.
    ' It can span multiple rows.
    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("a10:af70")

    ' Set the destination range to start at column B and
    ' be the same size as the source range.
    Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
    Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
       SourceRange.Columns.Count)

    ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
    DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

    ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
    NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

    ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all
' data is readable.
SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
```

End Sub

Comment: Copy it and then paste it where?

Comment: new summary workbook